# Transform a LinRange in array in Julia

Tags: arrays, vector, julia

I am new to Julia and I am trying to transform a LinRange to Array for further calculations. For example I have:

```
julia> x = LinRange(0, 1, 100)
```

With output:

```
100-element LinRange{Float64, Int64}: 0.0,0.010101,0.020202,0.030303,0.040404,0.0505051,0.0606061,0.0707071,0.0808081,0.0909091,0.10101,…,0.89899,0.909091,0.919192,0.929293,0.939394,0.949495,0.959596,0.969697,0.979798,0.989899,1.0
```

Then I transform it in array using:

```
julia> x = [x]
```

With output:

```
1-element Vector{LinRange{Float64, Int64}}:  range(0.0, stop=1.0, length=100)
```

But when I try to access it as a normal array

```
julia> x[1]
```

I have the entire LinRange as output:

```
100-element LinRange{Float64, Int64}:  0.0,0.010101,0.020202,0.030303,0.040404,0.0505051,0.0606061,0.0707071,0.0808081,0.0909091,0.10101,…,0.89899,0.909091,0.919192,0.929293,0.939394,0.949495,0.959596,0.969697,0.979798,0.989899,1.0
```

And if I try to access the second element I get this error:

```
julia> x[2]
```

`ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Vector{LinRange{Float64, Int64}} at index [2]`

I understand that I should "go a level down", but how can I do it? Trying for example with `x[1,1]` outputs always the entire LinRange.

Comment: `[x]` creates a "vector of vectors". In other words, you made a vector with one element, which is a range, you did not transform the original range at all. Going 'one level down' would be `x[1][1]`, not `x[1,1]`. But are you sure you need to transform the range in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
collect(x)
```

or

```
vcat(x)
```

or

```
[x;]
```

However, the question is why do you need a `Vector`. Unless you need to mutate it it is more efficient to work with `LinRange`.